# Oracle PL/SQL find nearest object

Tags: oracle-12c, plsql, nearest-neighbor

There are two tables containing objects and their coordinates. One contains hotels, the other contains restaurants. How to build a table that for each hotel lists nearest restaurant name and the distance?

```
WITH restaurant AS (
           SELECT 'A' r_name, 0.0 x, 0.0 y FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'B' r_name, 0.0 x, 6.0 y FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'C' r_name, 9.5 x, 0.5 y FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'D' r_name, 8.2 x, 4.7 y FROM dual -- etc           
           ),

     hotel AS ( 
           SELECT 'First_Hotel' h_name, 1.0 x, 6.0 y FROM dual UNION ALL  
           SELECT 'Second_Hotel' h_name, -4.0 x, 3.0 y FROM dual -- etc
           )               

     select h.h_name, r.r_name as nearest_restaurant, distance from restaurant r, hotel h  /* some query */
```

Should return

```
 hotel          nearest_restaurant    distance
 First_Hotel       B                    1     -- B is the nearest restaurant to First_Hotel. Distance is sqrt((1.0-0.0)^2+(6.0-6.0)^2)=1
 Second_Hotel      A                    5     --if both A and B on the same distance choose based on r_name
```

---

Edited: I also have `geoloc` for both tables with x and y coordinates. Can geoloc help to build the query?

Comment: what if  two restaurants are at the same location?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026675/calculating-distance-between-two-points-latitude-longitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query worked for me. It uses GEOLOC from Oracle Spartial

```
    create table my_result_table as  (
    select n.nodeid, n.geoloc.sdo_point.y as node_y, n.geoloc.sdo_point.x as node_x, 
        r.geoloc.sdo_point.y as sl_y, r.geoloc.sdo_point.x as sl_x,
        sdo_nn_distance(1)  as sld
       from  my_nodes n,  my_restaurants r
       where
       sdo_nn   ( r.GEOLOC, n.geoloc,  'Unit = MILE sdo_num_res = 1', 1) = 'TRUE'
        );
```

Note that first argument is restaurants, not nodes.